# Function in Jquery passing form element's ID as parameter

Tags: jquery, function, parameters

I'm trying to make a function in Jquery that will take the ID of form SELECT element's ID where a dynamically created option should be displayed. But, i have to repeat this work for other form instances as well. i have created the following code, but it did not work.

### JQuery Script

```js
function getOffice(ID){
    $.post('dynamicOffice.php',{operator:$(this).val()},function(output){
    $('ID').html(output);
    });
        $('ID').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

### Main HTML File

```html
<select id="senderOperator" name="senderOperator" tabindex="1" onchange=getOffice(sender)>
    <option value=""><--SELECT an Operator --></option>                 
        <?php getOption($operator,Operator) ?>
</select>

<select id="sender" name="sender" tabindex="1" disabled="disabled">
    <option value=""><--SELECT the Operator First --></option>
</select>
```

### dynamicOffice.php

```php
<?php
include('generateOption.php');
    $country=$_POST['operator'];
    $officeSql="SELECT * FROM myoffice WHERE Operator='$country'";
    getOption($officeSql,Name);
?>
```

### generateFormElement.php

```php
<?php
include("include/dbConnect.php");       

function getOption($rsSql,$colName){

    $sResult=mysql_query($rsSql) or die("Could Not Fetch Records");

    while ($s_Office = mysql_fetch_array($sResult))
    {
        echo("<option value='".$s_Office["$colName"]."'>".$s_Office["$colName"]."</option>");
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 17):

Remove the quotes from around the parameter, and concatenate a `#` to the beginning of it.

```
$('#' + ID).html(output);

$('#' + ID).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Also, `this` will likely reference the `window` instead of whatever element you expect, so the following won't work:

```
{operator:$(this).val()}
```

If it should reference the `select` element, then add `this` as a second argument:

```
onchange=getOffice(sender,this)
```

...and reference it with a parameter:

```
function getOffice(ID, el){
    $.post('dynamicOffice.php',{operator:$(el).val()},function(output){
        $('#' + ID).html(output);
    });
    $('#' + ID).removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Ugh, *answer* the question first, and **then** edit the question...sigh. When will I learn..? =/

Comment: Actually, +1 because I forgot to remove the quotes from around the variable, too. Sigh...and the rest of your answer made yours better than mine was likely to be. =D

Comment: @DavidThomas I had the exact same thing. I was editing the question, but you beat me to the question edit too!